# What is "Daemon is running!" on Blender startup?

Tags: python

When starting up a new Blender instance I see "Daemon is running!" in the lower left-hand corner of my 3D viewport. Does anyone know what this is? Is this something usual (I just never paid attention), or some plugin process doing a thing, or something else? The message goes away eventually but always appears at startup. Either it's new or I just never noticed before.

I use BlenderKit which displays messages in the same area and text style. Wondering if it's related to that.

[image: Daemon is running!]

Comment: Hello ! It's definitely an addon that's causing this. If you can narrow it down to blenderKit, then that's it. Not much else we can help you with unfortunately :)

Answer (score 6):

Can’t say for absolutely certain, but I am almost sure this is coming from blenderkit. The add-on is connecting to an external source to download resources in a very integrated manner, so I’m not surprised that it might run a background daemon. You can, of course do a little science yourself to make absolutely sure, but since it’s not actually a problem, in fact, it’s apparently a report that something is working successfully, I’m not sure why you’re concerned about it.

Comment: They do use a daemon: [Issues · BlenderKit/blenderkit](https://github.com/BlenderKit/blenderkit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+daemon)

Answer (score 1):

This message comes from BlenderKit add-on which uses a background process (http server) to schedule tasks and requests to online server with database of assets. The main goal of the message is to inform you - the user - that the daemon process is running and that you can expect the add-on to be working just fine, you should be able to search, download or upload assets once you see the message. So at this point you do not need to pay any attention to the message. Another story would be when you do not see the message...

At that moment you might expect some malfunction in the add-on, the search might be broken and you should inspect the logs. As rule of the thumb:

- green messages are just informative, to confirm all is good, no need to inspect them really
- yellow messages means something unexpected happened, add-on might work ok after this, but there is also chance, that it got broken
- red means there was an error, which prevented something from finishing - a search might never give results, daemon is down, not responding etc. Red messages are something to really pay attention to.

(I am BlenderKit add-on developer.)